# ASP.NET SelectList obtain value and display it

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to select an item an then display it in the view but i don't know how to pass the value to the controller.

this is my code created via scaffold:

Controller

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["ClienteID"] = new SelectList(_context.Cliente, "ID", "RUC");
        ViewData["ProductoID"] = new SelectList(_context.Producto, "ID", "Nombre");

        return View();
    }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Cliente" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select asp-for="ClienteID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ClienteID"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Model

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RUC { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Venta> Ventas { get; set; }

    public Cliente()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use Html.DropDownListFor ?

Comment: @CyberProgs Because I'm new to asp.net :(

Comment: read this http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: @CyberProgs thank you, I'll check it out